# Hide system message while running ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using the code bellow to grab an image from a video file and it is working great.
But when i am running the php file that contains the code bellow all system procceses appears, and i mean some infos about the convertion, export etc.

How can i make it run silent?

```
$stderr = system("ffmpeg -i $videoPath -vframes 1 -an -s 306x173 -ss 03 $finalfilename 2>&1 >/dev/null", $exit_status);

if ($exit_status === 0) {
    print 'Done! :)';
} else {
    print 'Error... :/';
    // $stderr will help you figure out what happened...
}
```

Comment: Use `exec` which does the same thing but doesn't output anything

Answer (score 1):

You should change the order of redirections. Like this:

```
>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or direct everything directly to /dev/null:

```
>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: On other question I'd suggested Irene to use that to get only `STDERR` contents on `$stderr` if command fails for some reason, just to help figure out what happened wrong if needed... I just made a mistake using `system()` in place of `exec()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `-loglevel quiet` as a [global option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis) but this will not be helpful if you experience errors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: sorry! On the other question I made a mistake suggesting you to use `system()` function, but you clearly need the `exec()` one.

Furthermore, you might want to suppress any `ffmpeg` verbose output with `-v error` to get only error messages on `$stderr`. You also need to pass `-y` to avoid getting stuck when `$finalfilename` already exists. Fixing all together:

```
exec("ffmpeg -v error -y -i $videoPath -vframes 1 -an -s 306x173 -ss 03 $finalfilename 2>&1 >/dev/null", $stderr, $exit_status);

if ($exit_status === 0) {
    print 'Done! :)';
} else {
    print 'Error... :/';
    // implode("\n", $stderr) will help you figure out what happened...
}
```